# How to register Asp.net Identity Role Manager in Simple Injector

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2, simple-injector

How do I register this using Simple Injector? Currently I have this error below

> The constructor of type ApplicationRoleManager contains the parameter
>   with name 'store' and type IRoleStore that is
>   not registered. Please ensure IRoleStore is
>   registered, or change the constructor of ApplicationRoleManager.

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
    {

        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> store) : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options,
            IOwinContext context)
        {
            var appRoleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            return appRoleManager;
        }
    }
```

on simple injector I have this below code but still the error persist

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<RoleManager<IdentityRole,string>,ApplicationRoleManager>();
```

Comment: You should read [this](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/564822) first.

Comment: Found it a while ago as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record if anyone in case have the same issue like me,
here is what I've found which can also be found in [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/564822)

```
container.Register<ApplicationRoleManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.Register<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, RoleStore<IdentityRole>>(
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```